# No me inicia el apache en ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu

php de la carpeta html del /var/www y después desinstale el apache. Lo volví a instalar pero no me crea el index.php. el error que me da en la terminal es:

Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50409/discussion-on-question-by-rafael-hernandez-no-me-inicia-el-apache-en-ubuntu).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza perfecto. Muchas gracias. Para la próxima voy a tener en cuenta. No sabia

Comment: Si llegaste a solucionar podrías marcar como solucionado. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenes que crear un archivo index.php en la raíz de tu VirtualHost.

Entra en tu carpeta, crea un index.php. Y dentro escribí un código como

```
<?php echo "Hola Mundo";
```

Luego guarda y volvé al navegador.